# IntelliJ IDEA - Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Does the title sound familiar to you? I initially thought it was a duplicate because I found similar questions, but I couldn't find any answers. I managed to resolve it, but the approach doesn't seem right. Also, I would appreciate an explanation.

First thing first, I am currently using IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2, I just download it this week to play with my Java codes. Now I tried creating a new project with Gradle, then created a main class that prints simple hello world then I got this warning.

[image]

I spent already an hour trying to solve this but no luck. Most of the solutions I found suggest to use `'--warning-mode all'`  just like what it said on the warning. But how can I actually do this spicifically on this version of IntelliJ IDEA? I don't see any options similar to what I found online.

I got lucky after exploring the Gradle settings and accidentally change the settings in the `Build and run` option. Warning gone after setting it from `Gradle (Default)` to `IntelliJ IDEA`.

[image]

But how this actually solved the problem? Is this even consider as the correct way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If this warning does not appear when you build your project from command line (e.g., with `./gradlew build` command), it worth reporting to JetBrains public [issue tracker of IDEA](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) as a bug. Give steps to reproduce and attach a sample project if possible.

As to change, that solves the problem. When `Build and Run using` is set to `Gradle`, IDEA literally invokes Gradle commands to build and run your project. When doing so, something goes wrong and IDEA touches deprecated APIs of Gradle, causing warning.

When you switch to `IntelliJ IDEA`, the IDE uses built-in compiler and execution support, bypassing Gradle. Thus, no deprecated warnings.
You can read a bit about [story of this switch here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2023/06/history-of-gradle-delegation-process-in-intellij-idea/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and this is how I see more info of it:

If you click on the little `...` button in the run result window, there is a button saying "Modify Run Configurations", do that, you will then go to a new gradle run configuration of running a main method, from there, you can put the suggested flag then you can see more info.

[image]

Running as this, gives such output:

```
13:22:29: Executing ':Main.main() --warning-mode all'...
```

> Configure project :
> Initialization script '/private/var/folders/66/3fbp21ys3z7fw8nrz08glkyh0000gn/T/Main_main__1.gradle': line 27
> The Project.getConvention() method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecated_access_to_conventions
> at Main_main__1_a6ld2zchxk76wb2mxv67tkx98$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall$original(/private/var/folders/66/3fbp21ys3z7fw8nrz08glkyh0000gn/T/Main_main__1.gradle:27)
> (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
> Initialization script '/private/var/folders/66/3fbp21ys3z7fw8nrz08glkyh0000gn/T/Main_main__1.gradle': line 27
> The org.gradle.api.plugins.Convention type has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 9.0. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#deprecated_access_to_conventions
> at Main_main__1_a6ld2zchxk76wb2mxv67tkx98$_run_closure1$_closure2.doCall$original(/private/var/folders/66/3fbp21ys3z7fw8nrz08glkyh0000gn/T/Main_main__1.gradle:27)
> (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

And you can even click on this generated
`Main_main__1.gradle:27` file so it is done by IntelliJ magically behind that some temporary gradle file is created and used for running the main method.

I guess IntelliJ will fix it soon.

So for now if you want to avoid it avoid this warning, perhaps you can write up a simple gradle task via [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task type (see the example in the doc or do it like below if you use kotlin dsl):

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  java
}

tasks.register<JavaExec>("runApp") {
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = "org.example.Main"
}
```

Then you can do:
`./gradlew runApp`

Answer (score 0):

By changing

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

and

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
```

to

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

and

```
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

I was able to fix the error and compile the project.
This happened after migrating Gradle from 7.4.2 to 8.2.2